# XSS vulnerable site

Tags: php, security

I have a test web site "www.site.com/test/2.php" for learning. When I opened site in browser there is downloaded file with duble quote('') name.

When I opened the downloaded file there is "Hello" word in site source code only html code and this

```
Hello
```

code.

This is the background code of the site.

```
<?php

require 'flag.php';

$input = $_GET['token'];
$input = str_replace(array("\n", "\0"), '', $input);

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$input'");

print "Hello. $input";

?>
```

For this I understant [www.site.com/test/2.php?token=](http://www.site.com/test/2.php?token=)alert('XSS');
But, it is not worked and burp show me "Proxy service started on 127.0.0.1:8080".

Can anyone say me where is here xss vuln?

Comment: unclear what your after, your code is simply inserting whats in `$input` in a couple of places. `?token=alert('XSS')` would make your header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='alert('XSS')'` (which is not valid) and `print "Hello. alert('XSS')";`

Comment: There is a response result from burp

Comment: You need to add <script>. Try `?token=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%27Hello%27)%3C/script%3E.html` and see the magic.

Comment: It's funny that the ultimate host associated with this is `octagon.net` where, on the homepage, the headline is `"We protect you against cyber attacks."`

Answer (score 0):

You should never trust user input. The received `token` doesn't check, so the vulnerability opens. You will probably be interested in this question: [XSS in Content-Disposition](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95017/xss-in-content-disposition)